# Unable to change UIInputView height

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout, uiinputviewcontroller

I have a simple UIInputViewController subclass with only two overridden methods. I use this input view controller as `inputAccessoryViewController` on my UIViewController subclass which becomes first responder. I try to specify height of inputView by adding constraint as Apple documentation recommends.
Problem is that my constraint doesn't work and I get autolayout exception when my constraint is being added

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
...
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178aa1d0 V:[UIInputView:0x178a4ae0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178b9520 V:[UIInputView:0x178a4ae0(500)]>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178b9520 V:[UIInputView:0x178a4ae0(500)]>
```

Which I think means that system already added a zero height constraint to the input view (because it is created with zero height). Now they conflict and autolayout breaks my constraint to fix the issue.

When I try to use it as `inputViewController` of my view controller (just for test purposes), I get same exception but instead of zero height it is 216 px. It also breaks my constraint and the height remains default.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints {

    CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                 multiplier:0.0
                                   constant: _expandedHeight];
    [self.inputView addConstraint: _heightConstraint];

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

As a result, I am not able to change input accessory view height. Has anyone succeed in it?  Obviously, Apple documentation provides no help...

Comment: V:[self(0)] is very strange – who added this constraint? Obviously, it needs to be fixed or at least removed.

Comment: May be a hacky solution, but in updateConstraints find that 0/216 constraint (actually all constraints on just height, except yours) and set it's priority to lower value, for it to be skipped silently on conflicts.

Comment: @user3125367 "who added this constraint?" - exact question I'm looking an answer for :) I'll try your suggestion and post later, thanks!

Comment: Try subclassing your view, overriding `addConstraint:` and see who calls it. Post the stack trace here.

Comment: @LeoNatan addConstraint is called only with my constraint. No previous calls to my view... I assume it gets added to some superview of the inputView. I'm stuck at the same point

Comment: overriding addConstraint seems to only catch constraints added by user, not system generated ones. It seems that whatever was used as height for the frame on initialize is added as a constraint somewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since iOS 9.0 this can be solved with `inputView.allowsSelfSizing = YES;`

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this answer. It took me half a day to find it with my humble search skills. It is exactly what solved the problem for me even in iOS 16.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the issue, but the problem may come from the 0.0 multiplier you are setting on _heightConstraint. Try to change it to 1.0.

It would look like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                 multiplier:1.0
                                   constant: _expandedHeight];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you make a view the input accessory view of a UITextView, as soon as the text view becomes first responder, a height constraint is added automatically set to whatever was sent as the frame height. For example:

```
let inputView = UIInputView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, 200), 
    inputViewStyle: .Default)
someTextView.inputAccessoryView = inputView
someTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
assert((inputView.constraints().last as NSLayoutConstraint).constant == 200)
```

You can modify this constraint after the fact.

Comment: note, only works if you don't have setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstrants

Comment: This should be the correct answer, works for me (so long as constraints are not being translated to autoresizing mask)

Comment: It's about the inputAccessory view of UIInputViewController not the one of someTextView. I don't know why you are talking about that one... It's independent each other

Answer (score 0):

I did it in Swift.
hope this helps you.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:self.view,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem:nil,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier:0.0,
        constant:100)

    self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```