# iOS Keyboard Extension how to add subview under keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, subview, inputview, uiinputviewcontroller

Im making iOs Keyboard extension, now I add animation when user type something like in default iOS keyboard. Something like this:

[image]

I just move my UIButton layer upper like this:

```
button.layer.position.y = button.layer.position.y - button.layer.bounds.height
```

Everything is ok but everything under top line of keyboard is hidden, looks like clipSubviews = true. I try change it to controller.inputView and controller.view but nothing helps.

[image]

Button with "t" must be under keyboard.Please help.

Comment: I find this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969737/drawing-outside-uiinputviewcontroller-frame :((

Answer (score 0):

On my experience I just designed my keyboard a little bit less.
Than you will get extra space on the top.

Comment: Not sure id call this a solution.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to display key artwork above the top edge of a custom keyboard’s primary view, as the system keyboard does on iPhone when you tap and hold a key in the top row.